# How to populate a Multi-Dimensional array (2d matrix) in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I wrote a function that creates such a Multi-Dimensional array(2D matrix) with zeros, and then tried to replace zeros in this matrix with digits of populateArr[ ... ] writinga new function ,but nothing worked.

WHAT I NEED  ↓↓↓
I need to write a function that replace the  zeros  in this matrix with numbers of "populateArr[ ... ]" array.

```
I should get 
[1,4,6],
[9,25,43],
[12,8,3],
[10,56,72],
[23,14,66],
]
[ [ 1, 4, 6 ], [ 9, 25, 43 ], [ 12, 8, 3 ], [ 10, 56, 72 ], [ 23, 14, 66 ] ]  with numbers from let populateArr = [1, 4, 6, 9, 25, 43, 12, 8, 3, 10, 56, 72, 23, 14, 66];
```

Thank You in advance.

First I tried using Array.prototype.fill(), but nothing worked, then I wrote another function, but it also does not work. work, I still don't understand how to populate this array.

Here Im sharing my code.

```
function createMatrix(rows, cols) {
    let arr = [];
    let result = '';
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= rows; rowIndex++) {
            let column = [];
             for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
                column.push(0);
            }
            result += `[${column}], \n`;
            arr.push(column);
        console.log(populateMatrix(rows, cols)); 
        }
        
        result += ']';
        console.log(result);
        return arr;
}
console.log(createMatrix(4, 3));

function populateMatrix(rows, cols) {
    let populateArr = [1, 4, 6 , 9, 25, 43, 12, 8, 3, 10, 56, 72, 23, 14, 66];
   let populated =  createMatrix.push(populateArr);
   console.log(populated);
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, and showed what I want to get

Comment: the digits of the populate(arr) should replace the zeros

Comment: I did it again.

Comment: Why would a 4x3 matrix end up with 5 rows after being populated with data?

Comment: `createMatrix` is a function, why do you call push, as it would be an array?

Comment: it should insert populateArr [ ... ] digits in place of zeros

Comment: please provide your original matrix with values being zeros and not and the final output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop and replace zeros:

```js
let populateArr = [1, 4, 6 , 9, 25, 43, 12, 8, 3, 10, 56, 72, 23, 14, 66];

function createMatrix(rows, cols) {
  let out = [];
  while(out.length < rows){
    out.push(Array.from({length: cols}, () => 0));
  }
    
  return out;
}

const matrix = createMatrix(6, 3)
console.log('source:', ...matrix.map(JSON.stringify));

function populateMatrix(matrix, arr){
  let i = 0;
  for(const row of matrix){
    for(let j = 0; j < row.length; j++){
      if(row[j] === 0){
        row[j] = arr[i++];
        if(i === arr.length) return;
      }
    }  
  }
}

populateMatrix(matrix, populateArr)
console.log('populated:', ...matrix.map(JSON.stringify));
```

Comment: source: [1,0,0] [0,0,0] [0,1,1] [1,1,0] [1,1,1] [1,0,1]
populated: [1,1,4] [6,9,25] [43,1,1] [1,1,12] [1,1,1] [1,8,1] 
getting some 1 s but i need in source only zeros and only the numbers of populateArr[...] in populated

Comment: @DanielHakobyan it will populate a matrix with all zeros also

Comment: @DanielHakobyan i've updated the answer

Comment: Good job, thank you very much

Comment: I have edited your code and get what I want)

Comment: @DanielHakobyan glad it helped, you are welcome 

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a `length` parameter to automatically create arrays and populate them with the 2nd `mapFn` parameter.

Use the `index` parameters passed to the `mapFn` to walk the `populateArr` and fill values, falling back to `0` once you exhaust those available.

```js
const createMatrix = (rows, cols, fill) =>
  Array.from({ length: rows }, (_, row) =>
    Array.from({ length: cols }, (_, col) => fill[row * cols + col] ?? 0),
  );

const populateArr = [1, 4, 6, 9, 25, 43, 12, 8, 3, 10, 56, 72, 23, 14, 66];
console.log(createMatrix(5, 3, populateArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: it must replace the zeros not only create an array with that numbers

Comment: @DanielHakobyan what's the difference?

Comment: there is not difference, only my task say first make an array with zeros after that replace,your code is working well, only that's my task, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting [an answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) to split the source array into chunks like the PHP `array_chunk` function

```js
const createMatrix=(size=3,source=[])=>{
  return source.reduce((a,i,x)=>(a[x/size|0] ??=[] ).push(i) && a,[]);
}

let size=3;
let numbers=[
  1, 4, 6,
  9, 25, 43,
  12, 8, 3,
  10, 56, 72,
  23, 14, 66
];
let matrix=createMatrix( size, numbers );

console.log( matrix )
```

Comment: it must replace the zeros not only create an array with that numbers

Comment: which zeros? please clarify The only zero in there is in `10`

Comment: when you are runing this code function createMatrix(rows, cols) {
    let arr = [];
    let result = '';
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= rows; rowIndex++) {
            let column = [];
             for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < cols; colIndex++) {
                column.push(0);
            }
            result += `[${column}], \n`;
            arr.push(column);
        console.log(populateMatrix(rows, cols)); 
        }
        
        result += ']';
        console.log(result);
        return arr;
}
console.log(createMatrix(4, 3));

Comment: there appears a matrix full of zeros

Comment: and i want to write a new function that will replace that zeros with digits of array populateArr[ ... ]

Comment: Both approaches of @Phil & the above yield the result you initially specified in the question., When I first saw this question there was no mention of Zero and needing to replace zeroes - Now looking back through all the edits it is hard to tell what you really do want and which edits were correct and which were not.

Comment: ok ok you are right